# IOException every time when calling SerialPort.BaseStream.EndRead()

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port

I try to get data asynchronously from a serial port. Mainly because DataReceived event seems not to be reliable enough and we end up with RXOver errors.
Target is .NET 4.0, so we need to use the older Begin/End methods.

I also learned that it is needed to call BeginRead() within a thread from the ThreadPool, otherwise the initiating thread would have terminated already when processing the passed callback.

However, even with a pooled thread I **always** get an IOException "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request".
The underlying com port is open.

Any advise welcome.

```
    #region DataReceiving

    private readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    private void StartDataReceiving()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( state => this.AsyncDataReceiving() );
    }

    private void AsyncDataReceiving()
    {
        this.serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(
            this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length,
            asyncResult =>
            {
                try
                {
                    int actualLength = this.serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead( asyncResult );
                    byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy( this.buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength );

                    this.dataConsumer.Add( received );
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    this.HandleSerialError( ex );
                }

                // Setup receiving action again
                this.AsyncDataReceiving();
            }
            , null );
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Off topic but you are getting RX over errors because you are processing the data in the event handler. This blocks the serial port's polling thread and allows the driver layer buffer to overflow. You should place received data into a producer/consumer queue or buffer immediately and process it on another thread.

Comment: @Gusdor: Hmm, that's exactly what the call to this.dataConsumer.Add() does. So you would move the BlockCopy stuff down there?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't still getting a port error in an `ErrorReceived` handler? I really can't recommend using a serial port via its `BaseStream`. You simple can't abstract them away like that.

Comment: Pretty important to realize that you are *not* ahead with this code.  It isn't any better at emptying the receive buffer than DataReceived.  RXOver is a fire-hose problem, you'll have to use the Handshake property to avoid it.  Why it trips isn't very clear, maybe garbage collection is taking too long, so also increase ReadBufferSize and consider lowering Baudrate.  Also pretty likely you are forgetting a lock to protect *dataConsumer*.

Comment: @Gusdor: Yep, I'm sure that there are no errors in the ErrorReceived handler, before or while calling EndRead(). There's logging and currently a breakpoint.

Comment: @Gusdor:First I also had the straight implementation using DataReceived event and BytesToRead, passing every received frame as quickly as possible to another thread for parsing and processing. However, this did not work out as a stable solution. Eventually we still got RXOver's. I found an article that the design of SerialPort and its Properties is not reliable. So I wanted to give this async version a try. I just didn't get that far with it.

Comment: @Hans: The cause for the RXOver errors is clear. However, we cannot change baud rate, handshake or any other communication parameters. We are communicating with an embedded device, that does not behave nicely. It just passes data as quickly as possible at 115KBaud.

Comment: Then you have an unambiguous performance mandate, your code needs to be able to process at least 12KB of data every second.  If it cannot do that then something is inevitably going to go bang.  Use a profiler to discover delays, very likely you'll find the hangup since 12KB is not much for a modern machine, the kind that can keep up with gigabit Ethernet network cards.  Usually it involves too much overhead due to trying to display that much data or the considerable thread context switch overhead that you'll incur from storing tiny blocks of bytes on *dataConsumer*.